# How can a family of cosets be a partition of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, set-partition

$G$ a group with subgroup $ H \leq G $.

**Theorem:**
The family of all the cosets $Ha$ as $a$ ranges over $G$, is a partition of $G$.

I have a little bit of trouble understanding this. For something to create a partition it has to be disjoint, but how can a family of cosets be disjoint?

If we consider two cosets, lets say, $Ha$ and $Hb$ They must have an element in common, namely the identity element $e$. By definition of a subgroup; $H$ contains the identity element, but that means that $e \in Ha$ and $e \in Hb$ and $Ha$ and $Hb$ are not disjoint.

Comment: The only coset containing the identity is $H$ itself.  Other cosets cannot be subgroups.

Comment: Remember that cosets are not subgroups. They are indeed just sets, other than $He=H.$ A standard exerise in group theory is to show that two cosets are disjoint or are identical.

Comment: Cosets of a subgroup are equivalence classes. Do you know of what equivalence relation on the group?

Answer (score 1):

> If we consider two cosets, lets say, $Ha$ and $Hb$ They must have an element in common, namely the identity element $e$.

This is not true : if $e \in Ha$, then there is $h\in H$ with $ha = e$, so $a = h^{-1} \in H$ and $Ha = H$.

Actually, two cosets $Ha$ and $Hb$ are either disjoint or equal : if there is $g\in Ha \cap Hb$, there are $h,h'\in H$ such that :
$$g= ha = h'b$$
Then $Ha = H(h^{-1}hb)= Hb$.

Therefore, the *set* $\{Ha : a\in G\}$ is a partition of $G$

(Note that depending on your definition, the *family* $(H_a)_{a\in G}$ may not bt a partition, since each coset will appear several times)

Comment: On the note: depends on your definition of "partition". One definition is that a family of sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a partition of $A$ if and only if $\cup_{i\in I}A_i = A$ and for all $i,j\in I$, either $A_i=A_j$ or $A_i\cap A_j=\varnothing$.

Comment: True. Thanks for pointing this out !